# Reason behind placing undefined as a property to window object?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, there is a property `undefined` for `window` object. What is the use or reason for that. What is the problem in placing `undefined` independent as `null`. We cannot find `window.null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One application I could think of (Might not be a very practical scenario)..

**`undefined` is **NOT** a reserved keyword in javascript. We can
   declare variables with name `undefined`)

**null is a reserved keyword.**

```
var undefined = "test"; //Valid 
var null = "test"; //Invalid
```

Things can get really weird if you have a function like below that declares a variable with name `undefined`

```js
function checkUndefined() {
  var undefined = "test";
  var a; // Has a value of  undefined
  var b = "test"; // Has a value of  "test"
  
  if (a === undefined) { // Not checking for
    //value undefined but comparing with variable undefined which 
    //has  value "test"
    console.log("a is undefined")
  }

  
  if (b === undefined) { // Not checking for
    //value undefined but comparing with variable undefined which       //has value "test"
    console.log("b is undefined")
  }

}


checkUndefined();
```

In the above code snippet, the equality checks `a === undefined` and `b === undefined` are not really checking for **value `undefined`** but for **variable `undefined`** (which I have set to string `"test"`)

To avoid this we could use `window.undefined`. As per docs..

> The global undefined property represents the primitive value
>   undefined. It is one of JavaScript's primitive types.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

And the property attributes of undefined says `Writable: no`, we cannot overwrite it using 
`window.undefined = "test"`

```js
window.undefined = "test";
console.log(window.undefined);
```

Having known that, we could rewrite the original function `checkUndefined` as

```js
function checkUndefined(){
    var undefined = "test";
    window.undefined = "test"; // Will not overwrite the property

    var a; //Has a value of  undefined
    if(a === window.undefined){ //Checking for window.undefined           //which is always the value undefined
        console.log("a is undefined")
    }

    var b = "test"; //Has a value of  "test"
    if(b === window.undefined){// Checking for window.undefined           //which is always the value undefined
        console.log("b is undefined")
    }

}


checkUndefined();
```

Same applies to `NaN` too. It's also **NOT a** reserved keyword.

As per MDN docs

> NaN compares unequal (via ==, !=, ===, and !==) to any other value --
>   including to another NaN value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN)
```

The below function declares NaN as a variable which masks NaN as a value in equality operators

```js
function checkNaN(){
  var NaN = "test";
  console.log(NaN === NaN); //Actually Comparing  "test" === "test"
}

checkNaN()
```

To avoid this we could use `window.NaN`. But we usually check `NaN` using global `Number.isNaN()` or isNaN() to most clearly determine whether a value is NaN.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nithin. Your answer throw lot of new information for me.